# Correct merge sort

Tags: javascript

So... If I input:

4 1 5 3

INSTEAD OF 1,3,4,5

I GET      [ 4, 1, 5, 3 ]

Following is the code for merge sort but for the last comparison the program doesn't fetch updated (1,4) (3,5) value rather (4,1) (5,3) thus giving the wrong result.

```js
 var a = [4, 1, 5, 3];
    q(a);
    function q(a) {
      var start = 0;
      var n = a.length;
      var length = parseInt(n / 2);
      if (n < 2) {
        return n;
      }
      var l = [], r = [];
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        l[i] = a[i];  //left array
      }
      for (i = 0, j = length; j < n; i++ , j++) {
        r[i] = a[j];   //right array
      }
      q(l);           //merge sort left array
      q(r);           //merge sort right array
      comp(l, r);
    }
    
    function comp(l, r) {
      var k = [], m = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
      while (i < ((l.length)) && j < ((r.length))) {
        if (l[i] < r[j]) {
          k[m] = l[i];
          i++;
          m++
        }
        else {
          k[m] = r[j];
          j++;
          m++
        }
      }
      while (i != (l.length)) {
        k[m] = l[i];
        m++;
        i++;
      }
      while (j != (r.length)) {
        k[m] = r[j];
        m++;
        j++;
      }
      console.log(k); //for final output it is [ 4, 1, 5, 3 ] instead of [1,3,4,5]

    }
```

Comment: I'm not following what you need. To sort the array? `a.sort()` - if there are multiple arrays then merge them, then `mergedArrays.sort()`

Comment: yes i want to sort array but by using merge sort whose implementation im trying to write.@DarrenSweeney

Comment: You are returning anything from function btw.

Comment: Can you give a better example of EXACTLY what you start with and what you want the end result to be?

Comment: there is single array and im sorting it through merge sort which uses recusrion (first left sort subarray,then right sort sub array, finally combine )
input 4, 1, 5, 3      output : 1,3,4,5

Comment: Your code is pretty hard to read.

Comment: Where are you using recursion though? :p

Comment: calling q function from inside  @Wimanicesir

Comment: @art can you create a code snippet to show the problem.

Comment: done @MaheerAli

Comment: May be [this](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-merge-two-sorted-arrays/) is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple small problems. The main one is that you are returning the wrong thing from your edge condition:

```
if (n < 2) {
    return n; // n is just a length; doesn't make sense to return it.
}
```

`n` is the length, you really want to return the small array here:

```
  if (n < 2) {
    return a;  // return the array instead
  }
```

Also, you need to pass the *result* of the recursive call to your comp function. Right now you're just returning the original lists with:

```
 comp(l, r)
```

Something like this would work better:

```
  let l_sort = q(l);           //merge sort left array
  let r_sort = q(r);           //merge sort right array
  return comp(l_sort, r_sort); // merge the arrays when recursion unwinds.
```

And you need to `return` things for recursion to work.

Put all together:

```js
function q(a) {
  var start = 0;
  var n = a.length;
  var length = parseInt(n / 2);
  if (n < 2) {
    return a;
  }
  var l = [],
    r = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    l[i] = a[i]; //left array
  }
  for (i = 0, j = length; j < n; i++, j++) {
    r[i] = a[j]; //right array
  }
  let l_sort = q(l); //merge sort left array
  let r_sort = q(r); //merge sort right array
  return comp(l_sort, r_sort);
}

function comp(l, r) {
  var k = [],
    m = 0,
    i = 0,
    j = 0;
  while (i < ((l.length)) && j < ((r.length))) {
    if (l[i] < r[j]) {
      k[m] = l[i];
      i++;
      m++
    } else {
      k[m] = r[j];
      j++;
      m++
    }
  }
  while (i != (l.length)) {
    k[m] = l[i];
    m++;
    i++;
  }
  while (j != (r.length)) {
    k[m] = r[j];
    m++;
    j++;
  }
  return k
}

console.log(q([4, 1, 5, 3]).join(','));
console.log(q([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]).join(','));
console.log(q([2, 3]).join(','));
console.log(q([3, 2]).join(','));
console.log(q([1]).join(','));
```